# Kivy: How to increment and decrement the count based on the mouse movement (on_touch_move)?

Tags: python, kivy

I would like to be able to display a counter value (0-360) in the middle of a circular knob, and then it will increment and decrement based on the on_touch_move event. As of now, I'm able to increase the value regardless the on_touch_move (counter clockwise or clockwise), but not sure how to set a maximum value and how I can decrement the value when on_touch_move is going downward. Not sure how this can be achieved in Kivy. I have done some research but couldn't figure out how to do it, here's the code I have so far:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.size = (781.274, 599)
import math
kv = '''
<Dial>
    canvas:
        PushMatrix
        Rotate:
            angle: root.angle
            origin: self.center            
        Color:
            rgb: 255,0,0            
        Line:
            circle:self.center_x, self.center_y, 112, 19, self.angle % -180
            width: 11        
        Color:
            rgb: 0,0,255    
        Line:
            circle:self.center_x, self.center_y, 112, 19, self.angle % 180
            width: 11
        Color:
            rgb: 255,255,255    
        Line:
            circle:self.center_x, self.center_y, 200, 500, self.angle % 45
            width: 10
        Color:
            rgba: .1, 1, .1, .9
        Line:
            width: 2
            circle:
                (self.center_x, self.center_y, min(self.width, self.height)/ 8.5,)           
        Color:
            rgba: .502,.502,.502,1
        Ellipse: 
            pos: (850,410)
            size: (214,214)
        PopMatrix                      
'''
Builder.load_string(kv)
class Dial(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Dial, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.touch_move_count = 0
        self.touch_move_Label = Label(text = " RPM", pos=(905,470), font_size=40, color=(10,10,255,1), halign="auto")
        self.update_count()
        self.add_widget(self.touch_move_Label)
    angle = NumericProperty(180)
    def update_count(self):
        self.touch_move_Label.text = str(self.touch_move_count) + "°F"
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        y = (touch.y - self.center[1])
        x = (touch.x - self.center[0])
        calc = math.degrees(math.atan2(y, x))
        self.prev_angle = calc if calc > 0 else 360 + calc
        self.tmp = self.angle
    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        y = (touch.y - self.center[1])
        x = (touch.x - self.center[0])
        calc = math.degrees(math.atan2(y, x))
        new_angle = calc if calc > 0 else 360 + calc
        self.angle = self.tmp + (new_angle - self.prev_angle) % 360
        self.touch_move_count +=1
        self.update_count()
class DialApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Dial()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    DialApp().run()
```

Comment: I see that the elements "blue" and "red" if they are changing through touch, you could give more details of what you expect to obtain since pointing to *increment and decrement based on the on_touch_move event* is very general.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. So when I move the mouse, currently the touch_count is returning incremental values, however, I would like to:                                     
1. set a maximum value where the touch_count would stop once the maximum value is reached                                                                                                            2. decrement the count value when mouse is moving in say counter clockwise direction

Comment: Do not explain to me about variables (since you might use other variables that have another concept) but about the GUI in general

Comment: basically when I move the mouse in clockwise direction, I expect to see the counter going from 0 to say 360, then it'll stop once the count reaches 360 as I move the mouse. Then it should go from 360 to 0 when I move the mouse in counter-clockwise direction.

Comment: Okay, so each angle variation equals a variation of the counter value?

Comment: They're not equal.

Comment: mmm, I already know that the counter takes values from 0 to 360 What values does the angle take? Could you show images of the angle for counter values 0, 90, 270 and 360 to understand you better?

Comment: It'll help you to understand better if you are able to run the code. So currently, the counter goes infinitely when I move the mouse regardless counter-clockwise or clockwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue myself. Basically write a "IF" statement to determine the new angle versus the initial angle, if it's greater than increment +1, if less than decrement -1.